# retrofit 2 error onFailure method

Tags: android, retrofit2

I got error in Retrofit 2 response

> MalformedJsonException Expected value at line 2 column 1 path $ on On failure function

Please help me I didn't understand what to do

This is json response:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "status_message": "Insert successfully",
    "data": {
        "imageresponse": "Uploaded successfully",
        "sueryId": 266
    }
}
```

when I send data with POST method without image upload it worked fine but when I send data with image RequestBody it give that error.

Comment: Probably your JSON request have a typo or you are using an unaccepted character.

Comment: share your `retrofit2` call

Comment: add response java class

Comment: Any one have idea why this error come what is the reason--MalformedJsonException Expected value at line 2 column 1 path $

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my Issue... response which i get from server is not proper from back end side.. that means if that kind of error just come because response is not formed Thanks guys for reply...